# How do I make the numpad go away after entering numbers into a UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I am trying to make an app that allows me to record numbers up to a certain number then add them like a calculator for a Science Fair Judging App. I have the numbers all work but I can't make the numpad go away.

Comment: `[textField resignFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

on the `UIViewController` that hosts your `UITextField`s. This will make them resign the first responder, and therefore dismiss your numpad.